# Package not detected after renamed in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project in intellij and when I created my packages I made a mistake because they all start in capital letter, for example my previous package name was "Main" then I changed it to "main" and I did it to all of my packages.

> error: package com.myproject.thesis.main does not exist import
>   com.myproject.thesis.main.Main;

but the "main" package and "Main" class does exist and already imported on the class that needs it. Also what should I name the package where I put my main class?

Comment: I don't think there's an answer to the second question.  There's no convention that I know of.

Comment: What OS are you running?  (I don't know if it makes a difference, but if you're on an OS where there's no distinction between upper and lower case in file or directory names, it's possible that IntelliJ may not handle this situation correctly.  Just a guess on my part, though.)

Comment: I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

While it may not help in this case, a general thing to try when "My code compiles and runs, but IDEA is really confused about the symbols in my project" is to go into the "File" menu and choose "Invalidate Caches / Restart". I've rarely used it, and it doesn't always help, but every once in a while it fixes IDEA's confusion.

See also the IntelliJ IDEA help on [Cleaning System Cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit configuration. From IntelliJ Run menu choose Edit Configurations. On the configuration window change the package name of Main class.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the packages to something else first. e.g. coma.myprojecta.thesisa.maina and get that to work. Then change it back to com.myproject.thesis.main. I think IntelliJ might be having problems with the change in case. If you change it something totally different and then back it IntelliJ should realise that things have changed.

As for what to call the class with main method, it is up to you. There is some good advice here. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208062/naming-conventions-for-java-classes-that-have-a-static-main-method

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a complete reset of the project. Create a whole new project, with the packages named (and cased) the way you want. Then, move the code files from your old project into the folders for your new project. IDEA should be able to see the files you put in there and parse them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the contents in /target (or "mvn clean"), and Intellij can find your new package correctly.

Comment: This question has already been answered. Also, the OP never stated that they were using Maven. Please make sure your answers on old questions add relevant or updated information to the question posed.